# Sending back XML to Web Service

Tags: iphone, service

I have a problem regarding Web service. I can Parse the XML obtained from the web service but I need to send the back to the web service with modifications. Example will be to send text answers to questions back to web service.

how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We would first need to know what development platform you're using to provide a correct example.

Comment: I am working on iPhone application development.
Sorry, I forgot to mention.